# use of $event in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What exactly $event in angularjs does? Suppose I pass it in a function from the template, what all properties can I use in the controller? I have used it in a few cases but have not understood what exactly it does.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - $event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)

Answer (score 1):

The term $event is used to access the value the directive passed to the method. Access the target property of the event object, for details of an event.

Answer (score 1):

From the Docs:

> ## $event
>
> Directives like `ngClick` and `ngFocus` expose a `$event` object within the scope of that expression. The object is an instance of a [jQuery Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) when jQuery is present or a similar jqLite object.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - $event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)

#### Common Event Properties

jQuery normalizes the following properties for cross-browser consistency:

- target
- relatedTarget
- pageX
- pageY
- which
- metaKey

The following properties are also copied to the event object, though some of their values may be undefined depending on the event:

altKey, bubbles, button, buttons, cancelable, char, charCode, clientX, clientY, ctrlKey, currentTarget, data, detail, eventPhase, key, keyCode, metaKey, offsetX, offsetY, originalTarget, pageX, pageY, relatedTarget, screenX, screenY, shiftKey, target, toElement, view, which

For more information, see [jQuery API Reference - Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)